# How do i check user is uploading any pics or not

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using formset and allowing users to upload multiple images. It worked. But the problem is if the user is not choosing any pics for upload, then the following code is saving `submitter`. If the user is not uploading any image, then I don't want to save `submitter`. Is this possible?

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    for image_form in formset:
        pics = image_form.save(commit=False)
        pics_image.submitter = request.user
        pics_image.save()
```

Comment: Do you mean `pics_image.submitter = request.user` line? Add something like `if pics.image:` before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formset.save()` does more processing than simply iterating on forms to save them.

Thus you'll need to check `form.has_changed()` manually.

Or rely on [`formset.save(commit=False)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) which return instances to save

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    for img in formset.save(commit=False):
        img.submitter = request.user
        img.save()
    # formset.save_m2m() # if there is any m2m to save
```

Comment: thanks but getting error `object has no attribute 'save'` here is a full [traceback](http://dpaste.org/5LwQ8/).

Comment: @Richard What's the type of `RecipeImageFormFormSet`? Please post relative code. only ModelFormSet has `save()` method

Comment: @Richard ah, use `modelformset_factory(RecipeImage, RecipeImageForm)` instead of formset_factory, the latter generates `FormSet` instead of `ModelFormSet`

Comment: thanks alot. But I am facing one more problem. when I open my form.  [link](http://imgur.com/oVc0I). If i use form_factory then its displaying like [this](http://imgur.com/KiuBr). am i missing something? thanks

Comment: @Richard If you mean the second formset does not show existed images, you need to pass queryset to `formset()` in `GET` and invalid `POST` branches: `formset(queryset=...)`